# How can I organize laravel routes without repeating controller and functions?

Tags: php, laravel, web, controller, routes

I have this code, but it's very verbose. How Can I write that shorter?

```
Route::get('/transaction/index', 'TransacaoController@index');
Route::get('/transaction/test1', 'TransacaoController@test1');
Route::get('/transaction/test2', 'TransacaoController@test2');
Route::get('/transaction/test3', 'TransacaoController@test3');
Route::get('/transaction/test4', 'TransacaoController@test4');
```

Comment: Can you add more explanation? Like what will each one of your routes do? And what the result should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're talking about the Route Prefixes in Laravel.

**Route Prefixes
The prefix method may be used to prefix each route in the group with a given URI. For example, you may want to prefix all route URIs within the group with admin:**

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        // Matches The "/admin/users" URL
    });
});
```

Extracted from https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Answer (score 1):

It might depends on how you prefer organize your infrastructure. Writing less not always is synonym of order.

You can use `group()` to apply middleware or prefixes to your routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['custom'], 'prefix' => 'transaction'], function(){
    Route::get('/index', 'TransacaoController@index');
    Route::get('/test1', 'TransacaoController@test1');
    Route::get('/test2', 'TransacaoController@test2');
    Route::get('/test3', 'TransacaoController@test3');
    Route::get('/test4', 'TransacaoController@test4');
});
```

Now, there is another option (does not recommended). You can use a unique route making the separation of your logic at controller level:

```
Route::get('/transaction/{action}', 'TransacaoController@action');

function action($action){
    if ($action == 'index'){
         // ...
    }
}
```